# How to add username in URL with htaccess or with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, .htaccess

I want to add username just after domain in URL, It should have to look like this `http://xx12.com/username/gallery`, Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue ? Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can register a route that accepts username as an argument like this:

```
$route['(:any)/gallery'] = 'YourController/YourMethod';
```